# Calculating equation in PIC

Tags: embedded, pic, numerical-analysis

Before I ask the question, I  will give the background of the problem.

My PIC 18F assembler routine solves Rntc to T°C  relation.
But the  precision at best is 3 digits.

The NTC reference resistance   I used in the assembler  example, is 10000  ohms corresponding to a Temperature of 25°C.

With only  3 digits available, the equation solution is =xF6 ,d246
Showing on the display  of T, the decimal point  between 24 and 6.

The time to  calculate  T, including Newton approximation is about 800us.  This calculation time looks  much better than  MPlab C

The assembler routine to calculate the sqrt of the equation 
y = 9.228*x*x-840.852*x+25236.82  runs  into the problem of scaling
b2-4ac ...the numbers overflow my 24bit maths suite  when I attempt to include the decimals   e.g. I have to use a=9 . b=840 c=25236

Q1  using integers, is there some trick to calculate the above numbers using 24bit maths ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think one really needs much more than about 10 bits of precision.

The equation `sqrt(a* x^2 + b*x + c)`, x=178..1196   gives pretty much linear response. One doesn't even have to go to a piecewise linear approximation using look up tables.

The linear equation would be y=`3.03x-129`

**EDIT**: the equation can be further simplified by noticing that 0.03*x ~= 8/256 * x;
thus `y=a+(a<<1)+(a>>5) - 131; // 8/256 = 0.03125 to be precise.`

The constant is modified to 131 to fine tune the error to ~zero mean.
The plots show the relative error (left) and absolute error (right) for `180<x<1200`

[image: Relative vs Absolute error]

Comment: Many thanks  Aki Suihkonen, I tried the linear y = mx +c  as you suggest. i.e. y =-408.867*x +20693. Unfortunately at 25ºC the equation indicates 26ºC  which is the worst deviation..  Actually for my application , a fast thermometer the error of 1ºC is acceptable. many thanks.